# How do I sort Value in descending order and Key in Alphabetical order using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is what I did,

```
Dictionary<string, int> colorRank = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

//Code to fill the dictionary.

```
var result = colorRank.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value).ThenBy(i => i.Key);
```

It's sorting the Value's to Descending order but not sorting Key's in Alphabetical order. Any Suggestions?

Comment: That should be correct code. Can you provide an example, what you expected, and what you got as a result?

Comment: @gunr2171 Never Mind, That is the correct code. I misread the results and Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected. You are overwriting your first sort. You can only notice the difference if you have repeated values in the values, Then the list of the keys for that value will be sorted alphabetically as you expect. So your code is correct and so is your expectation. Notice keys for 10 in the below example for your code.

```
public static void methodSort()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> colorRank = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        //Code to fill the dictionary.
        colorRank.Add("bla2", 10);
        colorRank.Add("bla1", 1);
        colorRank.Add("bla3", 11);
        colorRank.Add("blay", 5);
        colorRank.Add("blay1", 10);
        var result = colorRank.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value).ThenBy(i => i.Key);

        foreach (var v in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{v.Key} {v.Value}");
        }
        /* Output
           bla3 11
           bla2 10
           blay1 10
           blay 5
           bla1 1
         */
    }
```